What were some of the measures put up by the Austrian Empire to encourage Friulian identity?
In "The White War: Life and Death on the Italian Front 1915-1919" by British historian Mark Thompson, in the "Year Zero" chapter on page 144 (2009 edition) one reads

Further north [of the Isonzo Front], in Carnia, even the locals who were not Slovene and spoke something a bit like Italian, larded with Germanic and Slavic terms, were quite unlike the Venetians. The first Italian officials to make their way up these valleys after the 1866 war did not know how to classify the locals: were they German or Italian? These settlements shared an Alpine culture that linked them with the north and west; they also lay close to trade routes that connected the Mediterranean with central Europe.
The Austrians had tried to dilute Italian nationalism by encouraging the regional identity of Friuli. There was and is a Friulan identity - as the Italian state has accepted since 1945.

What are some of the concrete measures that the Austrian Empire adopted to dilute Italian nationalism specifically by encouraging the regional identity of Friuli, before the Third War of Italian Independence? Were any of these measures specific to Friuli?
